# Angular2 - importing third-party modules

Tags: angular

I am trying to import a the phoenix_js NPM module into my Angular2 app (initiated with the Angular2 CLI), but I am getting the error `Cannot find module 'phoenix_js'`.  I have seen a lot of other people facing the issue of importing third-party modules in CLI-initiated projects, but none of them work for me - my file structure seems to be different than everyone else's...

For starters, my Angular2 CLI version is `1.0.0-beta.22-1`, and I am trying to import it into a service like so: `import { Socket } from "phoenix_js";`  The phoenix_js module was installed with good ol' `npm install --save phoenix_js`.

From my research, I get that third-party libraries need to be explicitly included in the `system.config` file, but the latest version of the CLI uses Webpack and so it does not have such a file.

I'm inexperienced with both Angular2 and Webpack - any guidance as to how to tell my app that yes, the module does exist, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you run the app. Check if the package was really added to package.json on installation, Webpack won't be happy if it wasn't due to some error.

Comment: Thanks, @estus - I was able to figure out a solution, answered below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a `typings.d.ts` file to my `src` directory... in the file, I wrote `declare module 'phoenix_js';`, which I could then import into the module/components as needed by writing

```
import * as phoenixJS from 'phoenix_js';
```

For a more complete explanation - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation